# Как включить отображение жестких дисков на рабочем столе и в боковой панели Finder?

Tags: macos

я отформатировал жесткий диск на своем mac и переустановил OSX, но при этом ЖД теперь называется просто "Новый" и его нет в finder и на рабочем столе в общем как это исправить?

Comment: Две недели как купили и уже успели сломать и починить. Хорошая работа ))

Comment: Кстати, если вы хотите использовать разные ОС дополнительно к OS X, то посмотрите в сторону Parallels. В виртуалке все отлично работает и там как раз есть решения «из коробки», чтобы установить Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы видите рабочий стол, значит OS X успешно установилась и жесткий диск не потерян. Отображение его на рабочем столе и в сайдбаре Finder это вопрос настроек.

Откройте окно Finder, нажмите  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>;</kbd> , чтобы открыть настройки.

Тут устанавливается отображение ярлыка на рабочем столе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А тут — на сайдбаре.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Переходишь в папку "выше" cmd+uparrow до диска и тащишь в боковое меню. Переименовать в настройках можно.